# Is there a "strings" tool that gives useful results on .NET binaries?

Tags: .net-framework

I need to get a list of all the strings in my application. But when I run the Sysinternals "strings" tool, the strings I care about are mixed in with a lot of strings like "DataSet" and "get_value". It looks like class and method names are being treated as strings.

Is there a way to get useful results on .NET binaries?

Comment: I think that you will have to define "useful results" if you want to get useful results from this question.

Comment: Hopefully the compiler placed all the procedures/functions/classnames in a different string section from the static strings. If so, your "relevant" strings are clustered together. See if you can find bounding offsets/identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, EBGreen. I need a list of the strings that are coded in the application. I don't want anything else, like class names or internal .NET strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ildasm` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, included in Windows SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and then filter on [ldstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instructions:

`ildasm "your_exe_or_dll" /text |find "ldstr"`

(you could also spit out metadata with `/metadata=heaps` and then look for section 'User Strings')

Answer (score 1):

If running the application is ok, you can run the SysInternals [Process Explorer](http://www.sysinternals.com/Utilities/ProcessExplorer.html). If you look at the properties of the process, you can see the strings in memory as well as the strings in the process image. You can also safe/export those strings if you like.

[image: Strings properties in Process Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx), the sysinternals `strings` tool has an optional parameter `-n` that you can use to indicate the minimum length of the string you are looking for, as the default is 3.

Comment: That's what I ran. Because the strings include a lot of class names, there are strings that I need to see that are shorter than the strings I don't want. But thanks.